# How many Ishta Devi and devatas are there?

Tags: ishta-devta, mantra-diksha

For a mantra Diksha there should be an Ishta for the practitioner, so I wanted to know how many Ishtas are there ? Also is there any deity who has imagination , knowledge , creativity as Saraswati and Ganesha , success and fortune as Laxmi and strength and fierceness as Kali and Kartikeya assimilated into one deity?

Comment: Please can anyone answer the 2nd question as I want to worship the accumulated strength altogether.